# Environment variables in perl

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I seem to be able to access environment variables in perl just by doing:

```
use Env;
print ${PATH};
```

Is this expected behaviour?

The [Env docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html) say you need to do `$ENV{PATH}`.

Answer (score 16):

The [Env](http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html) says

> Perl maintains environment variables in a special hash named `%ENV`. For when this access method is inconvenient, the Perl module `Env` allows environment variables to be treated as scalar or array variables.

So yes, this is legitimate and the expected use of variables is `$PATH`, `$USER`, `$HOME`, etc.

However, this module

> By default it ties all existing environment variables (`keys %ENV`) to scalars.

and I prefer to use the [`%ENV` hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%ENV) directly, rather than its [tie](https://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)-ed counterparts. (See the source code for the core `Env` module on [its CPAN page](https://metacpan.org/release/Env/source/lib/Env.pm).)

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is expected behavior, due to the interaction of two factors:

1. You used the `Env` module, which aliases `$ENV{PATH}` to `$PATH`.

Note that `$ENV{PATH}` is *always* available in Perl.  `use Env` just adds aliases to the contents of `%ENV`, it is not needed to make `%ENV` available:

```
$ perl -E 'say $ENV{LANG}'
en_US.UTF-8
```

2. `${PATH}` is nothing more than a more verbose way of saying `$PATH`.  The `${...}` construct (and its cousins, `@{...}` and `%{...}`) is most frequently used for interpolation within double-quoted strings, to force Perl to recognize the entire contents of the `{...}` as a variable name rather than a shorter name followed by literal text, but the syntax is also usable in other contexts.

A simple demonstration of this:

```
$ perl -E '$foo = "bar"; say ${foo}'
bar
```

Answer (score 8):

Use $ENV is predefined variable format in perl

```
print $ENV{PATH};
```

Comment: I can get it just be doing `${PATH}`.  Why?

Comment: Did you have `use Env;`?

Comment: NO u dont need to use any cpan module. u can directly use $ENV data structure to access environment variables